# Displaying items in C from an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have an 8x8 enum array that contains empty, red, white, k_red, k_white pieces. The array looks like

```
for(x = 0; x < BOARDHEIGHT; x++)
{
    for(y = 0; y < BOARDWIDTH; y++)
    {
    printf("%d |",board[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Which prints to the screen int values but I would like them to show instead of the int values an actual display defined as (for example)

```
#define WHITE_KING_DISPLAY "\x1b[39m" "O"
```

How do I go about making the array print that instead of its int value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your int values, i.e., the values stored in `board[x][y]`, are in the range `[0,4]` then you could simply define an array with string that you want as the print-outs:

```
char const *labels[5] = { WHITE_KING_DISPLAY, ... };
```

Then in your `printf`, instead of printing `board[x][y]` you print `labels[board[x][y]]`.

Comment: Use `char const*` whenever you point to string literals, as modifying them is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The value contained in the board array are enum with the values `WHITE`, `RED`, `K_WHITE`, `K_RED` you have to use condition statement such as if, or better switch statement. For the use of if else statement.
Example:

```
if (board[i][j] == RED)
{
printf("%s",RED_DISPLAY);
} 
else if (border[i][j] == WHITE){
....
}
```

The define in the pre-processor are strings and therefore a format specifier of `%s`. However, i do recommend switch statements, but i will let you explore this.